# Proof by basic principles of Riemann Integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be Riemann Integrable on $[a,b]$ and $f(x)\ge0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Show that $$\int_a^b f(x)dx\ge0$$ using basic principles of Riemann Integration.

I'm new to this concept of Riemann Integration. Apparently, I have to show that  $U(P,f)\ge0$ for any partition in $[a,b]$, which will prove that the integral itself is greater than or equal to zero.

But I'm unable to frame the proper statements, and I'm afraid I might make an assumption without really justifying it.

So, can somebody please show me how to write a formal proof in such a case?

Comment: But if a $f$ is Riemann integrable, isn't $U(P,f)=L(P,f)$?

Comment: No, please check your definitions: that f is Riemann integrable means that sup L(P,f) over every partition P and inf U(P,f) over every partition P coincide, not that L(P,f)=U(P,f) for every partition P. *Exercise:* Determine the functions f such that L(P,f)=U(P,f) for every partition P (there are very few such functions...).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. You're right. $U(f)=L(f)$. I was confused.

Comment: Did you solve the exercise in my previous comment?

Comment: I guess constant functions will satisfy that property?

Comment: Indeed. Any other functions?

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: indeed, *in general*, if U(P,f)≥0 for every partition P then the integral I(f) is ≥0 since I(f) = inf U(P,f) over every P. Likewise, an equivalent condition for I(f)≥0 is that, for every positive s, there exists P such that L(P,f)≥-s (since it may happen that L(f,P)<0 for every P and yet I(f)=0). However, *in the present case*, to show that I(f)≥0 it is much simpler to exhibit *one* partition P such that L(P,f)≥0...

Answer (score 1):

Let $\int_a^b f\,$ be defined as a limit of Riemann sums.

Then for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for every tagged partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ with $\|P\| < \delta$ one has $$\left |\int_a^b f- R(P,f) \right| < \varepsilon$$ So, if $P$ is a tagged partition such that $\|P\| < \delta$, then $$\int_a^b f > R(P,f) - \varepsilon$$ Hence, if $f(x) \ge 0$ for very $x \in [a,b]$, then $$\int_a^b f > -\varepsilon$$

But $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary $\dots$

Comment: Their framework appears to already be that of Darboux integration, rather than the "seemingly more general" definition involving tagged partitions.

Comment: I agree, but it seemed to me that @Did had already given the answer in the last comment. So I decided to offer an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing the notation you are using you have $$L(P,f)\le\int f\le U(P,f)$$
You can use the function which is identically $=0$ as a step function from below, and for this, quite obviously, the integral is $=0$. So you are done.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is a Riemann integrable function, then for any partition $P$, the lower sum $L(P,f)$ is less than or equal to the integral, while the upper sum $U(P,f)$ is greater than or equal to the integral. If you pay attention to the quantifiers, you find that to show that the integral is larger than some number $c$, it is enough to find a single partition whose lower sum is larger than $c$.

In this case you can take the simplest partition of all, where there is just the single subinterval $[a,b]$. Over this interval there is some infimum, which must be nonnegative; then the lower sum is this infimum times $b-a$, which will again be nonnegative.